# Question regarding derivation of the quadratic formula

Tags: solution-verification, quadratics

To derive the quadratic formula, I want to find $(m,n)$ such that
$$ax^2+bx+c+p=(mx+n)^2+c$$
Expanding the RHS reveals
$$ax^2+bx+c+p=m^2x^2+2mnx+n^2+c.$$
Then,
$$a=m^2,b=2mn\implies (m,n)=(\pm\sqrt{a},\pm\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}})$$
From here, isolating and solving for $x$ would be trivial.

Would this general method be correct? I'm confused as to the significance of $p$ since $p=n^2 \implies n=\pm\sqrt{p}$ here as well.

Perhaps it's been a long day or my algebraic skills have worsened, but I just couldn't seem to work out the quadratic formula with this path of thinking; there would always be some extra term...

I'm aware that dividing the entire original equation by $a$ simplifies things a lot, but that should just be a specific case of this general form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The $c+p$ can be simply replaced by a constant say $k$, then all you have to do is to express $ax^2+bx+k=(mx+n)^2+j$ and get the expressions for $m,n,j$. As \begin{align*}m^2&=a\\2mn&=b\\j+n^2&=k\end{align*} So $j=k-\frac{b^2}{4a}$ and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formulation isn't quite right. If you're trying to solve $ax^2+bx+c=0$, you could look for $(m,n,p)$ such that
$$
ax^2+bx+c=(mx+n)^2-p.\tag1
$$
Setting the LHS of (1) to zero is then the same as setting the RHS to zero, which yields
$$
x=\frac{-n\pm\sqrt p}{m}.
$$
To obtain $m, n, p$, you proceed as you've done: Expand the RHS of (1) and match coefficients on powers of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the significance of $x=\frac{-n\pm\sqrt p}{m}$ here?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you plug in the values you found for $m,n,p$ you should obtain the quadratic formula: $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It seems I was a little confused when I had commented!